# Changing text color in drop down menu on magento?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, magento

I have 10 color choices on my Magento store. I've tried for several hours to get the black to have a black background, white have a white background and so on.

From the app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php file:

```
    $_option = $this->getOption();
    $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
    $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

    if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN
        || $_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
        $require = ($_option->getIsRequire()) ? ' required-entry' : '';
        $extraParams = '';
        $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setData(array(
                'id' => 'select_'.$_option->getId(),
                'class' => $require.' product-custom-option'
            ));
        if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
            $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().']')
                ->addOption('', $this->__('-- Choose Option --'));
        } else {
            $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().'][]');
            $select->setClass('multiselect'.$require.' product-custom-option');
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $select->addOption(
             '"style="background-color:'.$_value->getTitle('Black').';color:#000000""'.''.$_value->getOptionTypeId('Black'),
             $_value->getTitle('Black')
       );
        }
        }
```

I can NOT figure this out. How can this be done? I have colors like black, red, white, orange, purple etc. I want the colors highlighted that color in the drop down menu.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a piece of HTML code produced by the PHP process ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your generated HTML to look as that:

```
<select>
   <option val="1" style="background-color:#000;color:#FFF">Option 1</option>
   <option val="2" style="background-color:#00F">Option 2</option>
   <option val="3" style="background-color:#0F0">Option 3</option>
   <option val="4" style="background-color:#F00">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

[the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMHGb/) sample.

Comment: The code is suppose to call out the value which would be black or white etc.